# Android GPS_PROVIDER/api substituta?

Tags: android

Recentemente dei início a um projeto pessoal usando android, que usa o `GPS_PROVIDER` para saber a localização mais aproximada possível.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Existe qualquer outra *api* que eu possa usar pra substituir essa funcionalidade?

Gostaria de ter uma possibilidade de manipulação melhor dos meus pontos de localização sem depender de internet, algo como os GPS offline mesmo, que nós encontramos na play store, sem depender de qualquer sinal de rede.

Comment: Por que diz que o GPS_PROVIDER depende da internet? Quando usa LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER em `LocationManager#requestLocationUpdates()` o que vai ser usado para obter a localização é o GPS do dispositivo.